# how can i read out one specific value in the mtgox ticker api with php

Tags: php, arrays, api

with:
    https://github.com/1360/mtgox-api-v1-php-class/blob/master/mtGox.class.php

+

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($gox->getTicker(),true) . '</pre>';
```

i get all ticker information of the mtgox-api.

-> how can i read out only ONE value, e.g. the last price to buy:

```
[buy][value_int]
```

= 11350000

? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$gox->getTicker()` returns an array, you can reference an element of the array like this:

```
$response = $gox->getTicker();
echo $response['buy']['value_int'];
```

Comment: @MartinGöpfert I am glad to hear that this is working for you! To help others find this solution in the future, will you upvote and mark it as correct? Thank you!

Comment: i can't upvote at the moment: quote: upvote requires 15 reputation -> will upvote it later when i'm able to do so..